# Text on each image in image carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I want to change the text on each image in an image carousel. I've tried using separate `<div>` for each image, but it's still not working.
This is the type of image carousel:[Space Gallery](http://www.eyecon.ro/spacegallery/#about) 
The source code is available. I am not able to implement as desired. Anyone with possible solution?

```
<div id="myGallery" class="spacegallery">
                <div>
                <img src="images/bw3.jpg" alt="" />
<!--This is my text that i want to put-->
                <p class="gh"><strong>Here</strong></p>
                </div>
                <img src="images/lights3.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="images/bw2.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="images/lights2.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="images/bw1.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="images/lights1.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
```

I even tried this:

```
<div id="myGallery" class="spacegallery">
                    <div>
                    <img src="images/bw3.jpg" alt="" />
                  <span>  <marquee behavior="slide" direction="left">HTML slide-in text...</marquee></span>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <img src="images/lights3.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span><br/>Tadad</span>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/bw2.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img src="images/lights2.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img src="images/bw1.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img src="images/lights1.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

css:

```
span{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:100px;
    left:30%;
}
```

[image: The Result for the other code with<code><marquee></code>tag]

Comment: Where's your JQuery codes?

Comment: Please provide full code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) that enables us to replicate the issue you are having.

Comment: It is available in the link i've given.
But the text on top of image has to be thru css right?

Comment: All information **has** to be in the question. If the link dies this question is of no use. Show us what _you_ have tried. We can't help you unless you give us all the information required.

Comment: I have edited the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Follow below url may be help.
    http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/gXN2u/
```

Comment: But i have a doubt, in my code i have shown above,i neednt make any changes with the javascript right? html and css have to be proper?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another Gallery for this purpose with custom block support. If you check code of SpaceGallery - there is direct search of  or  elements.

One possible solution is to create javascript function and make `after` callback (spaceGallery support this) to create and position your text.

Comment: When i tried to input a text,i was able to do so for one image.But when i clicked,the text was repeating itself in the next image also.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with Spacegallery plugin. You have to use another plugin.

Or one thing u can add to image itself

Comment: No,i **need** a text itself

Comment: Either change in plugin on go for another plugin. But changing plugin is not best practice